# Django display user uploaded content

Tags: python, django, upload, render, django-urls

I have yet to wrap my head around django and URLs, and my confusion is now preventing me from doing what I feel like should be a very simple task.

I have successfully implemented file upload.

In my settings.py file, I have added the specifications for where to store the uploaded files and the URL Django should use to serve them.

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL= '/media/'
```

I also added the necessary line to urls.py to allow Django to serve files from MEDIA_URL.

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin
from login_app import views as login_app_views
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static


urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/',     admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^login/',     login_app_views.login_user),

    # creating registered namespaces for each app
    url(r'^login/',     include('login_app.urls',       namespace = "login_app")),
    url(r'^CMIRS/',     include('dashboard_app.urls',   namespace = "dashboard_app")),
    url(r'^CMIRS/',     include('submit_app.urls',      namespace = "submit_app")),
    url(r'^CMIRS/',     include('filter_app.urls',      namespace = "filter_app")),
    url(r'^CMIRS/case/',include('report_app.urls',      namespace = "report_app")), 
    url(r'^CMIRS/',     include('search_app.urls',      namespace = "search_app")), 
    url(r'^search/',    include('haystack.urls')), ##used in navbar-search

 ] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

In an app report_app, I want the webpage to display a hyperlink that can be used to view an uploaded file. When I click on the hyperlink, I want it to request the URL to the uploaded file.

The upload looks like such in my models:

```
upload1 = models.FileField(upload_to = 'documents/%Y/%m/%d/')
```

I am having trouble figuring out what to use in the render(request) in my view and how to correctly code this in HTML. When I attempt to use "media", I get an error saying it cannot be matched.

Here is a snippet of the HTML I am trying:

```
<dt>Upload</dt><dd><tr><td><a href="{% url 'media' case.pk %}">{{ case.upload1 }}</a></td></tr></dd>
```

I am also confused as how to set up my render(request) so that it knows to access media/, and then go to the correct documents/Y/M/D depending on the primary key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't want to use the url tag here at all. Your media's URL is stored in your model, and has nothing to do with Django's path resolution logic. Just reference the `url` method of the field:

```
<a href="{{ case.upload1.url }}">
```

See [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.fields.files.FieldFile.url).

(Note also that serving files via your urls.py like this works in dev only; for prod you'll need to configure your webserver to do it.)

Comment: thanks! Any advice for how to format the render(request, template, context) request? I'm assuming I don't need a template, as I just want to display the uploaded file, but I can't figure out how to properly address the file's url.

Comment: No, because I don't understand what render you are talking about.

Comment: Sorry! That's because that has nothing to do with my problem. The new code you provided me is not throwing me any errors, but when I click on the actual hyperlink, it does not transfer me to the file. What do I need to add to make that work correctly?

Comment: Where does it take you? What error do you see? (Note, I just noticed that my phone autocorrected the code; it should be all in lower case, edited now - that might fix whatever issue you are seeing.)

Comment: That fixed it! Before, it was just remaining on the same page (no error, no redirection).